# When changed web-pack server port from 4200 to 5003 API call again stop working

Tags: angular-cli

After changing my webpack server port from 4200 to 5003 my api call again stop working and now getting 401 Unauthorization error and if i revert back port to 4200 it works fine.
command to change port & proxy.config.json

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --port 5003

{
    "/api/*":{

        "target":"http://10.154.20.24:9090/dev",
        "secure":false,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the proxy configuration? What API?

Comment: Please [edit] the question

Comment: Authorization cookies are related to the host. Try to log out and log in again.